# Query for search engine brings back same results regardless of input

Tags: php, mysql

I'm writing a script for a search engine where all fields need to be able to have information submitted by themselves, or in combination with other fields. The fields are Name, City, State, ZIP, Country, Category_1. The code is below:

```
"SELECT * FROM table WHERE Name LIKE '%$get_name%' 
OR City LIKE '%$get_city%' 
OR State LIKE '%$get_state%' 
OR ZIP LIKE '%$get_zip%' 
OR Country LIKE '%$get_country%' 
OR Category_1 LIKE '%$get_category1%' 
LIMIT 0, 10";
```

If I echo all the variables, from the inputs, they all come out correct. However, the query brings up the same results regardless of what the user input was. Any suggestions? It seems to be a problem with the MYSQL query itself.

Comment: Put the query in a variable and echo it. Confirm that the values are not empty.

Comment: Just to make sure it is intended: They are all OR - so any of parameters given blank then it will return all data.

Comment: @smozgur I misinterpreted what the OR condition would do. Can you suggest a better condition to look into?

Comment: are you trying to get all criteria fields matched at the same time? then you need AND. Then you should still check for empty variables. Better idea, create your SQL string with the "valid" posted variables. And use AND if you want all fields to be match at the same time. I can provide a sample code for this if you have trouble to make it work.

Comment: Oh! It has been already posted as an answer by another user below. So you should be ok now but I still insist you need AND. The reason is: It will return all cities even user entered a specific city for the requested $get_category1 with OR. I guess this is explanatory enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if any of the variables is empty you will get all results.
its the same as `Name LIKE '%%'` = all results.

You can use it this:

```
$fields = array(
    'Name'  => $get_name,
    'City'  => $get_city,
    'State' => $get_state,
    'ZIP'   => $get_zip,
    'Country'   => $get_country,
    'Category_1'    => $get_category1,
);

$query = "";
foreach($fields as $k => $data) {
    if(trim($data) != '') {
        $query .= ($query ? ' OR ' : 'WHERE ') . "$k LIKE '%% $data'";
    }
}

if($query) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM table $query LIMIT 0, 10";
}
```

Comment: I guess I misinterpreted what the condition would do. Can you suggest a different condition to use?